# background process is taking lot of time via ajax

Tags: php, unix, background-process

I am using a background process in a php page. When I use normal post to this page it completes the action and initiates the background process and everything works really fast. But when i call the same php page via ajax, this is taking lot of time to get a response. I have identified that background process in only causing this delay.

Seems to be a bit strange, the same process is not taking time while using the traditional post method, but it really slow while calling from an ajax page

Please advice me what i am doing wrong

Comment: @user762317:)hows u call the php via ajax code?

Comment: You say it's taking a lot of time to get the response, does the response complete successfully and do what you expect in the end?

Comment: I got a fix for that now. I was using below command earlier

 shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/ww/html/backgroud.php {username_variable} &")

Now I changed that to

shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/ww/html/backgroud.php {username_variable} >/dev/null &")

After this it is working fine....

Any thoguhts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are detaching the process from your php script call now, while your script waited before until your background script finished.

Comment: shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/ww/html/backgroud.php {username_variable} >/dev/null &")

Comment: But make sure you `shellescapearg` the username. Otherwise, bad people may inject malicious commands.